# Why can't I center this div?

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar on the right and I want to create two centered together columns for Tumblr posts on the left. What can I do?

```
        #wrapper /*for two columns*/ {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 15px 15px 15px 30px;
        }
        #wrapper .posts {
            width: 400px;
            margin: 0 15px 15px 0px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        #sidebar /*including some other stuff, obviously*/ {
            display: table;
            width: 250px;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
         }
```

Comment: Please include the html

Comment: `display: table; height: 100%;` this will not work. You cannot control the height of elements that have `display: table;`.

Comment: @connexo However, it does work! And the problem is not the height, but the centring #wrapper!

Answer (score 1):

To make HTML elements center aligned:

For Block element such as `div, p, ..etc.,` these should have `width` or `max-width` set to some value and there should be `margin-left: auto` & `margin-right:auto`

For inline element such as `span, em, ..etc.,` we can center align by giving `text-align:center` to its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Your horizontal `margin`s on `#wrapper` should be set to `auto`. That’s the key. The parent (possibly the `body`) may need to also have set `text-align: center`.